# Mapping Cylinders with homotopy equivalent attaching maps

Tags: general-topology

Im struggling with the following problem: Let $M_f$ denote the mapping cylinder.

If $f_0 ∼ f_1 : X → Y$ , then $M_{f_0} ∼ M_{f_1}$ rel. $X × \{0\}$.

I believe the idea is clear: Instead of Deformation retracting $X$ to $Y$ in $M_f$ you leave $X$ invariant and change the way you "attache" $Y$ on $X$.
What throws me off, is that the Homotopy is now in the relation of the quotient space and my usual approach of descending the homotopy via universal property doesnt work.

How do you properly prove this i.e. how can i prove continuity of this deformation?

Thanks everyone

Comment: To correct the "homotopy" grammar in your title, it should say *Mapping Cylinders with homotopic attaching maps*. "Homotopy" is a relation between on continuous functions (with the same domain and codomain). "Homotopy equivalence" is a relation on topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_t$ be the homotopy. Consider the map
$$M_{f_0} \cong Y \cup_{X \times \{2\}} X \times [0, 2] \to Y \cup_{X \times \{1\}} X \times [0,1] = M_{f_1}$$
defined by mapping $X \times [1, 2]$ via $(x, s) \mapsto f_{s - 1}(x)$ (and symmetrically for $M_{f_1} \to M_{f_0}$). The composition on $M_{f_0}$ will be of the same form, with $f_t$ replaced by the homotopy $f_t \cdot {f_{1-t}}$ of $f_0$ (to itself). This is homotopic to the identity by replacing $f_t \cdot f_{1 -t}$ with $f_t|_{t \in [0,s]} \cdot f_{s - t}|_{t \in [0,s]}$ as $s$ varies in $[0,1]$.